# How to dispose shared variable in VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net

How to dispose the shared variable in vb.net

i am using shared object of Asterisk.NET Manager Variable, i assigned it in form load 
and i dispose it in main form closing, My problem is after closing the application, application.exe keeps live in task manager, if i not initializing the shared object in form load there is no problem,

My code in form open

```
  Public Shared WithEvents objManager As Asterisk.NET.Manager.ManagerConnection

  Public Shared Sub ConnectAsterisk()
    Try
        objManager = New Asterisk.NET.Manager.ManagerConnection(ELASTIX_IP_ADDRESS, ASTERISK_PORT, ASTERISK_USER_NAME, ASTERISK_PASSWORD)
        objManager.Login()            
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub



 Private Sub frmMain_FormClosing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    AsteriskManager.objManager = Nothing
End Sub
```

can any one please help to do that

Thanks,
Senthil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is not in the disposing of the ManagerConnection. 
Asterisk.NET Manager doesn't implement IDisposable.
You have to Logoff.

```
objManager.Logoff();
```

for vb.net would be

```
objManager.Logoff()
```

and then destroy the reference:

```
objManager = Nothing
```

Comment: “destroy the reference” makes no sense here. It’s a useless operation in this context.

Answer (score 2):

If you dispose the resource in the `Closing` event, it will be disposed as soon as *any* form is closed. This may work for you but it’s conceptually wrong if your resource is `Shared`.

Either remove the `Shared` qualifier from the variable or implement the [“static finalizer”](http://dotnet.mvps.org/dotnet/articles/sharedfinalizer/) idiom to remove dispose the resource at the end of the application lifetime:

```
' *In* frmMain.vb:

Private Shared Finalizer As New SharedFinalizer()

Private Class SharedFinalizer
    Protected Overrides Sub Finalize()
        MyBase.Finalize()
        objManager.Logoff()
    End Sub
End Class
```

The `SharedFinalizer.Finalize` code will be run exactly once, at the end of the application domain lifetime.

Answer (score 1):

You claim to dispose it, but I don't see that in your code.
You could call `Dispose` on it if it implements `IDisposable`.